# Top_toBottomof is not working in constraintlayout . How to use Top_toBottomof in Constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, mpandroidchart

I have this following layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_with_filter_back" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/banner"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="165dp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/win_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">


                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/exec_business_icon"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                        android:src="@drawable/icon_dairy" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/exec_business_iconname"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                        android:background="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:text="Foods"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h" />
                                </RelativeLayout>

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvRname"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/exe_size"
                                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h_valve"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/fb_sr_bu"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="SR"
                                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/fb_size_val_bu"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="56.9"
                                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/fb_bn_bu"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="BN"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/layer_5" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvgrowth"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/exe_growth"
                                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h_valve"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fb_growth_bu"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="+7.0%"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_growth_val_color"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_topplayer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/win_card"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/top_player_back"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/top_player"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                        android:text="@string/business_unit_top"
                        android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/orientation" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/business_lineChart"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Problem 1**:
When i set the second cardview height to match_parent then it takes the full screen instead of the left screen at the bottom. It means it will override the first cardview also and reach to the top of parent/screen. So in this case why the set constraint toptobottomof is not working and how can i make it work? As far as i know toptobottomof makes sure that your second view will always remain below of first view which in this case is not working.

**Problem 2:**
If i keep my layout as it is then the problem is the LineChart is not expanding at all. It is compressing the whole chart height into the wrap content height. It is not behaving like it needs more space as this is what wrap_content attribute is made for instead it is restricting the chart itself to that available height and its not expanding the cardview height at all.

Please help me with these issues.

Comment: Problem 1: For your view to adjust it size following constraints  set `layout_width` or `layout_height` to `=0dp`

Comment: view becomes dot sized with that

Comment: can u please share a screenshot of your current view and expected view?

Comment: Forgot to mention, you should set both of the vertical / horizontal constraints while using `=0dp`

Comment: @Quicklearner Just did please check

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov I set the constraint width and height to true with layout width and height to 0dp and the view is now invisible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change height to `0dp` of android.support.v7.widget.CardView , width to `0dp`
and use   `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
This will make the height fill to the parent

Add these

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Example

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_topplayer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/win_card">
```

Update
To implement scrollview use fillviewport = true

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 android:fillViewport = "true"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```

And Remove this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` from second `cardview` like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_topplayer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/win_card"
                >
```

Comment: Happy coding and always open to help..:)

Comment: The chart which i have created is a bit long and the whole layout needs to be scrollable and when i included NestedScrollView after <layout...> then the second card got disappeared. So how can i make this work with Scroll also as chart is a bit long

Comment: just did please check

Comment: Hi, any other suggestion for the last query with nestedscrollview?

Comment: still the same, i even tried by setting the height of scrollview and the 2nd cardview to match parent then the views get visible but only to the half of the screen

Comment: I have found the solution and have updated the answer according to that. :)